# Нужно ли перестраивать предложения (объединять, разъединять)?

Tags: пунктуация

> И юнцы наши – Сергей Безруков, Гоша Куценко, Слава Разбегаев, Денис
>   Бургазлиев, Алексей Панин, Филипп Янковский. Всех и не упомнишь, и
>   всех нас заставляли играть в этом спектакле.

Пробовала поставить многоточие после Янковского - не спасло.

А если так:

> И юнцы наши – Сергей Безруков, Гоша Куценко, Слава Разбегаев, Денис
>   Бургазлиев, Алексей Панин, Филипп Янковский... всех и не упомнишь, и
>   всех нас заставляли играть в этом спектакле.

Плохо?

---

Расширенный контекст - по просьбам трудящих:

> И вот представьте себе нас двадцатилетних – Настя Заворотнюк, Алена
>   Хмельницкая, Катя Семёнова, Вера Воронкова и прочие нынешние наши
>   умницы и красавицы  (я телевизор не смотрю, но точно знаю – всех их
>   видно). И юнцы наши – Сергей Безруков, Гоша Куценко, Слава Разбегаев,
>   Денис Бургазлиев, Алексей Панин, Филипп Янковский... всех и не
>   упомнишь, и всех нас заставляли играть в этом спектакле. Сначала,
>   конечно, многочасовые изматывающие репетиции, потому что для каждого
>   из участников находили постановочную позу, то есть некую мимическую
>   композицию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаете, а я ничего бы менять не стала, текст хорошо написан (я имею в виду полный вариант), и знаки препинания на месте. Дробить его на предложения и абзацы не стоит:  он читается "на одном дыхании", это одна тема.

И юнцы наши – Сергей Безруков, Гоша Куценко, Слава Разбегаев, Денис Бургазлиев, Алексей Панин, Филипп Янковский... всех и не упомнишь, и всех нас заставляли играть в этом спектакле.

Answer (score 0):

А если так ( *поширше*, контекста нет, додумываю ):

***И юнцы наши*** – Сергей Безруков, Гоша Куценко, Слава Разбегаев, Денис Бургазлиев, Алексей Панин, Филипп Янковский..**. - *всех и не упомнишь*.**  ***И*** **всех нас** [или всех их?] ***заставляли играть в этом спектакле.***

**Дополнение** *к расширенному контексту - по просьбам трудящих* (как-то так):

И вот представьте себе нас, двадцатилетних: Настя Заворотнюк, Алена Хмельницкая, Катя Семёнова, Вера Воронкова и прочие нынешние наши умницы и красавицы (я телевизор не смотрю, но точно знаю – всех их видно).
А юнцы наши – Сергей Безруков, Гоша Куценко, Слава Разбегаев, Денис Бургазлиев, Алексей Панин, Филипп Янковский?.. - всех и не упомнишь. И всех нас заставляли играть в этом спектакле! Сначала, конечно, многочасовые изматывающие репетиции, потому что для каждого из участников находили постановочную позу: некую мимическую композицию.

Comment: Две точки и запятая - такой знак недопустим. А контексту щас добавлю в вопрос...

Comment: Римма! Какое счастье - редактировать актёрские мемуары!..

Comment: Да... Главное:  никого -  из умниц и красавиц - ненароком не забыть